# Comparing stability of halide ions

Tags: halides

I have to compare stability of halide ions : $\ce{F-},\ce{Cl-},\ce{Br-},\ce{I-}$

I am confused between two factors : As we go down the group , the size of given species increases which *spreads* the negative charge more ( as incoming electron goes into a larger orbital and hence feels less repulsion) , however the electron gain enthalpy factor conveys a different result.

According to the first factor $\ce{I-}$ must be most stable but according to second factor $\ce{Cl-}$ must be most stable as chlorine's electron gain enthalpy is most negative.

I think here one factor should dominate over other but can't seem to figure out.

I searched various online  resources and each one contradicts the other.

Can you please guide me?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this depends on context; e.g. fluoride is most stable in aprotic, soft solvents but iodide is most stable instead in protic, hard solvents.